# s3cmd ls and sync command cost

Tags: amazon-s3, s3cmd, cost-management

When i use command to see a folder's contents

```
s3cmd ls s3://mybucket/my_big_folder/
```

Assume my folder contains 10000 files. How many LIST ops it will be? Only one or 10000 ops?

And the second question: how many ops will produce the "sync" command for my_big_folder if local and remote folders contents are the same?

It is important because I want to make a "cleanup" script (5m files in bucket + 1.5m for deletion) and in the case of 10000 ops per one request it will cost a dozen of money and my boss will not be happy of that :-(

Answer (score 2):

Commands that list the buckets do so in batches up to 1000 objects per request.  Delete commands, especially in [sync] operations, do batch deletes of up to 1000 objects per request also (batch delete recently added in s3cmd 1.5.2).  If the objects are large (>5MB by default; anything uploaded with multipart upload), in getting the object list it will also make a single request for each object.